# STARTTLS connection with Ruby and OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl, starttls

Using `openssl s_client` on the command line I am able to establish a comection to a POP3 server which requires STARTTLS.

```
openssl s_client -connect pop3.example.com:110 -starttls pop3
```

How can I accomplish the same (especially the `-starttls pop` part) utilizing Ruby's OpenSSL library:

```
tcp_socket = TCPSocket.new host, port
ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new tcp_socket, ssl_context
ssl_client.connect
```

Answer (score 2):

The POP3 specification states that you need to send `STLS` in order to initiate the TLS handshake. Therefore you should send `STLS` on the unencrypted socket first, and after that you should be able to call `connect` on the OpenSSL layer, which will then perform the actual handshake.

If you call `connect` before sending `STLS`, the server won't know what is going on, and will interpret it as garbage input.

Working example:

```
tcp = TCPSocket.new(host, port)

puts tcp.gets
tcp.puts 'STLS'
puts tcp.gets

ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ssl_client  = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(tcp, ssl_context)

ssl_client.connect
puts ssl_client.state

ssl_client.puts "NOOP"
puts ssl_client.gets
```

Output:

```
+OK POP3 ready <2067986403.1526483285@....>
+OK
SSLOK
+OK
```